# Making a period bold in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am working on something simple and hit a problem. I want to use a period as an index's display instead of numbers like 1,2,3,4 ... I blatantly just inserted period and it worked like I wanted it to but the size was small. I have been googling and haven't found a solution. Does anyone know an Ascii for something that I can use to make the period look like a bullet point(usually big) so anyone who's using my program can click on the big bullet(period).

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? Are you using HTML? (This is a completely wild guess, but you mention JavaScript and you talk about users clicking something, so...)

Comment: I am using the script in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a period and making it bold you can always use the Unicode bullet character:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm

In a javascript string it would be `"\u2022"` and it would look like this: •

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `li` HTML element ? More info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work" ? Using a special ASCII character to display a bullet point is not the right way to do what you want I think. Can you explain how you tried the ul/li tags and what did not work?

Comment: I understand li HTML element works like a list. In my case, I don't want a list of things. The thing I want from the li HTML element is the dark bullet. That's why using li HTML element won't work in my case. Thanks for posting. What I was looking for was "\u2022" which is a unicode bullet character.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but you could probably use an unordered list for this.

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item N</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want them as a list. I want to print out bold periods instead of using the numeric indexes. Something like ... instead of 123. The period are clickable though

Answer (score 1):

## Use Characters Entities or Unicode Characters

You could find a more suitable character using this [Wikipedia List of XML and HTML Character Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

For instance, these could do:

- ♦ (`&diams;`)
- • (`&#x2022;`)
- ‣ (`&#x2023;`)
- ◦ (`&#x25E6;`)
- ⁃ (`&#x2043;`)
- ∙ (`&#x2219;`)

You could also use a lowercase 'o' depending on your font.

## Or Use CSS Properties to Style Your Text

Define a CSS class:

```
  .periods {
      font-weight: bold;
      // anything else you want to style
  }
```

You want to achieve something like this:

```
  <span class="periods">.</span>
```

## If you Want a List...

Then use a CSS class like this:

```
.dotted-list li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  // or any other style as listed in the first table on:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-type
}
```

and a list like:

```
<ul class="dotted-list">
  <li>entry 1</li>
  <li>entry 2</li>
  <li>entry 3</li>
</ul>
```